# I am from Malaysia, should I have a return trip or a multiple trips by Eurostar?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, eurostar, chinese-citizens

I am from Malaysia, a Chinese. I am travelling with my boyfriend, who is an Englishman.

I will prepare some documents, such as:

1. Salary slips
2. Bank Statement
3. Itinerary of my trip
4. Accommodation address

If I have only a single ticket to Germany with him, can I enter UK with him without a return ticket? Or I should plan to other Europe countries by Eurostar?

Comment: What passport are you travelling on?

Comment: What's Eurotrain? Do you mean the Eurostar train between London and the continent or some EuroSomething trains in Germany and other countries?

Comment: I am travelling on 6 months holiday visa.
Yes, I mean the Eurostar train. :)

Comment: I am not sure I follow your itinerary: You live in Malaysia, will fly to Malaysia to Germany and then take the train to the UK? Or the other way around? When/how do you intend to leave the UK? Are you going to return to Malaysia eventually? What's your citizenship and do you have any visa? And what are you concerned about: Entry requirements for the UK? For Germany? Something else?

Comment: To the extent that a proof of onward travel is recommended in your situation, a flight out of the country or two separate Eurostar tickets should be just a fine. Even a flight from some other European country to your home country can often do. I cannot think of any situation in which having a “return ticket” is required as such.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was travelling to newhaven, England by ferry. The custom did ask me to show the return ticket when he asked me where was my next country to travel.

Comment: @Relaxed I am not sure if the tag 'Chinese-citizens' is warranted. Afaik in the context of Malaysia, being Chinese is more likely to mean [Malaysian-Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysian_Chinese) which in most cases have Malaysian citizenship and not Chinese citizenship. I think we should wait for the OP to come back and clarify on that.

Comment: @drat Sure, but why ping me about this?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to bother you. I thought that's how one is supposed to reply to a comment.